# Is there any good UAT online management website that is simple and effective?

Tags: user-acceptance-testing

Is there any good UAT online management website that is simple and effective? I have been looking for a while now to find a website out there to help me design tests and write documentation.

I know spreadsheet is the answer but looking for something more robust, ideally with notifications to help communication developer/tester

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at http://www.gurock.com/testrail/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of projects out there. I have used FogBugz, BugTracker, JIRA, and TFS.

As for templates, I have found this very handy:

> As a {role}, I want to {feature/action} so that I can {value}
>
> **Conditions (optional)**
>
> - Item 1...
> - Item 2...
>
> **Design/Dev Notes (optional)**
>
> - Item 1...
> - Item 2...
>
> **Acceptance Criteria**
>
> - Must allow ...
> - Must prompt ...
> - Must prevent ...
> - Must display ...
> - Broken Links {okay/unacceptable}
> - If… then…., else, and, but
> - Browsers
>
>   - additional {browsers/devices}
> - Styled
> - Responsive